# What is the time complexity of 'assoc' function in scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme

What  is the time complexity of this nifty function 'assoc'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume that `assoc` is O(n)*, assuming that `equal?` is O(1) in your usage of the function. This is because it's trivial to write your own version of `assoc`:

```
(define (my-assoc v lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((equal? v (caar lst)) (car lst))
        (else (my-assoc v (cdr lst)))))
```

You can see this simply slides down the list `lst` until a match is found. If none is found, `#f` is returned.

* technically `equal?` is O(n) where n is the size of the smaller input, so if you're comparing huge list structures using `assoc`, your runtime will be O(n*m) where `n` is the size of the list provided to `assoc` and `m` is the size of `v`.

Comment: To nitpick, m is the smaller of either the size of v or the average actual key size in the association list.

Comment: @Svante: true, but worst case is that v is smaller than every key in the assoc list, so it still holds